# Some named exports not working when setting absolute import paths with baseUrl (tsconfig)

Tags: typescript, tsconfig, absolute-path

In my `tsconfig.json` I added `"baseUrl": "src"` in order to use cleaner absolute imports.

The project structure is roughly:

```
|- src
   |- components
      |- someComponent
         index.tsx
   constants.ts
   types.ts
```

The idea is to change `someComponent > index.tsx` from:

```
import { someType } from '../../types';
import { SOME_CONSTANT } from '../../constants';
```

to:

```
import { someType } from 'types';
import { SOME_CONSTANT } from 'constants';
```

Everything works save for `constants`:

```
// constants.ts
export const SOME_CONSTANT = {
   value1: 'abc',
   value2: 'xyz'
}
```

Which when imported with the absolute path throws the error `Module constants has no exported member SOME_CONSTANT`.

(It does work with `from '../../constants'` relative imports).

The problem seems to be with the **named export**, since if I change it to a default export, it works fine:

```
// constants.ts
const SOME_CONSTANT = {
   value1: 'abc',
   value2: 'xyz'
}
export default SOME_CONSTANT; // added default export


// someComponent > index.tsx
import SOME_CONSTANT from 'constants'; // removed brackets
```

That said, for some reason it only happens with named exports in `constants.ts` but not with named exports in `types.ts`:

```
// types.ts    
export interface type1 {
   // ...
}
export interface type2 {
   // ...
}

// someComponent > index.tsx
import { type1 } from 'types'; // this works fine despite non-default export
```

Any idea of what might be the problem?

So far the only other clue I see is that when changing the absolute path import from `from 'constants'` to `from 'constants.ts'` it throws the error `An import path cannot end with a '.ts' extension. Consider importing 'constants.js' instead.`, not sure if it might be related.

**Edit:** my `tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2018",
    "outDir": "./build/",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": false,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "types": ["cypress", "@testing-library/cypress"],
    "baseUrl": "src"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```